# Merged AndroidManifest results in debuggable set to true for release build

Tags: android, android-manifest

I've been dealing with a weird annoying issue all day today. I recently took over a code-base and I was trying to upload the release buildType of the app for the first time to the play store (for internal track testing) and it kept reporting that debuggable is true. I went to check via APK analyzer the AndroidManifest, and indeed debuggable was set to true. So the journey to find the culprit began (so far no success).
Things I've checked/tried so far:

- Tried forcing debuggable to false in build.gradle, and also in the Manifest.
- Tried using `tools:remove="android:debuggable"`
- Tried replacing it via `android:debuggable="false" tools:replace="android:debuggable"`
- Checked the Merged Manifest tab, and the `android:debuggable` does not appear there
- I've gone through all the libs/dependencies to double-check that they don't have the attribute set (I know since I couldn't see it in the Merged Manifest tab, probably none have it, but I was out of ideas, so I checked that as well)

Any idea what I could be missing, or where else to check, or what to try?

Tooling:

- TargetSDK - 29
- CompileSDK - 29
- BuildTools - 29.0.3
- GradleW 6.5
- Note: Project has no flavors, and only the default buildTypes (debug and release)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I finally figured it out. the `debuggable` attribute in the manifest was being set to true due to `testCoverageEnabled=true` for the release buildType... I didn't know that was a side-effect of `testCoverageEnabled` but now in hindsight it somewhat makes sense. Kinda anti-climactic result, but I guess that's just another day in the life of a dev :D